# Dynamic Menu Layout in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a dynamic menu layout in ASP.NET MVC 4. What I did is in my shared view I have the following call

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("Index", "FooterMenu"); }
```

I have a controller, and a view for my FooterMenu. It also have a model. Now i try to call it however I keep getting this error

```
System.StackOverflowException was unhandled
```

Its keep pointing to my index

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View(db.FooterMenus.ToList());
}
```

It also say make sure i am not in an infinite loop, or recursion. But my code is fairly simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are caught in a recursive loop. My guess is that the Index view in FooterMenu is using the shared view, which itself is calling `@{ Html.RenderAction("Index", "FooterMenu"); }`

Comment: Oh, wow okay that make sense, how can i have a partial in shared folder, with data from the table? then

Comment: Return a PartialView instead of a View. The View creates a loop as spotted by Queti Mporta but the PartialView will only returns your menu (without layout which calls the menu another time)

Answer (score 2):

I would suspect that you want to return a `PartialView` - so that the menu doesn't also render  the layout, which renders the menu, which renders the layout, which renders the menu...etc

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return PartialView(db.FooterMenus.ToList());
}
```